# Major twist in The Winds of Winter which is not possible in HBO's Game of Thrones?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, game-of-thrones

> In a recent interview with IGN, George R. R. Martin said that the major twist in the sixth installment of his "A Song of Ice and Fire" novel series involves a character who's already dead on the HBO series but is still alive in the books.
>
> "The show can't do this, unfortunately, because they've killed a character I have not killed," Martin told the website.

Which character is Martin referring to here ?

> The only two major characters that the series has killed off but the book hasn't that I can think of are Jon Snow and Stannis Baratheon. Not sure which one he's referring to here though.

Comment: Re the first example in your spoilertag: ***really?*** I thought it was unclear in both book and TV series whether he was dead or not, and (spoiler!) the material so far released for season 6 suggests he probably *isn't* dead in the show.

Comment: That said, +1 for an interesting question, although I'm 98.6% sure the answer is "we don't know" and 83.4% sure that it will remain so until tWoW is released.

Comment: @randal'thor : I agree, that it was as unclear in the TV series as it was in the book, though the fact that the actor portraying that role has vehemently proclaimed throughout the last year that "<insert character here> is dead.", leads me to believe that GRRM maybe referring to him as well.

Comment: Voting to close as opinion based. There's absolutely no way to know this until TWOW comes out or GRRM spoils his own book...

Comment: @kuhl : I agree that we may never know the correct answer, but based on all the deaths leading up to this point in the series as well as in the books, I guess we could speculate on who Martin was referring to, and the very fact that GRRM mentioned the existence of such a character in an interview points to a possibility that there is non-opinion based answer to this as well.

Comment: Technically, the show has killed Caitlyn Stark but in the books she was resurrected by the red preist and now goes by the name Lady Stoneheart.

Comment: @stark there is a non-opinion based answer, but you'd need to be GRRM or a time traveler to know. Speculation is pure opinion and probably better suited to a site like westeros.org